# Can i use create-react-app into my projects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, create-react-app

If in future i need to change the code or some config (which is part of node modules), Is that will be a big headache?

What is the merits and demerits for using create react app?

Comment: If you want to customize the configuration beyond what `create-react-app` will allow, you can run `npm run eject` to get access to the underlying Webpack configuration. This is a one way operation, however - you can't go back to `create-react-app` once you've ejected.

Comment: Is that will create any problem in production, if i eject

Comment: Your project won't be any different after you eject, it just won't be managed by create-react-app any more. So for example, if the CRA team change how their internal Webpack config works, you'll have to update that manually on your project if you've ejected. See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup for more info.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding ejecting unless you're 100% certain you need to do something that CRA will not allow you to do. For most projects, just using CRA as is will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `create-react-app` and rest easily knowing that if you need to do any extra configuration at any point, you can always do `npm run eject` which will make all of the setup `create-react-app` does for you fully visible. [Read more about it here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#available-scripts).

I would suggest making a few applications configuring Webpack and Babel by yourself just to understand what's really going on and the purpose of it, but the convenience `create-react-app` is worth looking in to.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to start from scratch, or you can just create the boilerplate for your modules and reuse them in your apps.

Yes you can use the create-react-app in your project, but it entirely depends upon your project requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Create-react-app is a reliable way to make small projects with zero configuration. if you dont want to rely on that tool, it would be better to create your projects with some configuration(webpack) boilerplate and with time you can customize it to fit your needs.